# JavaFX TableColumn Show HashMapValue (Non Property)

Tags: javafx, hashmap, tableview, tablecolumn

I've a simple question but I'm stuck with it since hours. 
I have a Class `UnitMap` which extends `HashMap`

And a Class `AttackCommand` which contains an `UnitMap units = new UnitMap();`

I'm attempting to display the value of a MapEntry in my TableView:

```
@FXML
private TableColumn<AttackCommand, Integer> columnlkav;

@FXML
private TableColumn<AttackCommand, Integer> columnstart;

@FXML
private TableView<AttackCommand> tableview;

@FXML
private TableColumn<AttackCommand, String> columnname;

@FXML
private TableColumn<AttackCommand, Point> columntarget;

private ObservableList<AttackCommand> tableData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    AttackCommand ac = new AttackCommand();
    ac.getUnits().put(ConstantsUnit.UNIT_ID_LKAV, 5);
    ac.setName("Testname");
    tableData.add(ac);

    columnname.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<AttackCommand, String>("name"));
    columnlkav.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<AttackCommand, Integer>("units"));

    tableview.setEditable(true);
    columnname.setEditable(true);
    tableview.setItems(tableData);

}
```

So the shown entry in the TableColumn is logically {2=5}, because `ConstantsUnit.UNIT_ID_LKAV = 2`

How can i display the value proper? I tried a few examples from the net but don't get it

By the way: I don't use `SimpleStringProperty` for `name` and don't use other Property Classes in `AttackCommand` because I want to serialize the Data via EclipseLink to my DerbyDB.

Comment: What is the value you are wanting it to display? This should be the result of `ac.getUnits().get(ConstantsUnit.UNIT_ID_LKAV)`?

Comment: Okay, I've done it with `columnlkav.setCellValueFactory(
         cellData -> new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<Integer>(cellData.getValue().getUnits(ConstantsUnit.UNIT_ID_LKAV)));` Is there another way? Maybe a way where i can overwride `UpdateItem` so the User can change the Value? As I said I dont use Properties here..

Comment: That's the correct way. If your table is editable, you can call `setOnEditCommit` on the `TableColumn` to update the value in the model.

Comment: Woops, that was too obvious. :-) Thank you very much. You can post my own comment in combination with yours as answer and I'll accept it as right if you want.